# how to disable input text on condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image]i would want to disable some input text when a certain condition is met. one input text value will be used as a key of the condition. imagine having 6 input and 2 getting data from table and these getting data from table 1 to store condition value. i want a scenario like, if text2.value is 'test'  then text3 and text 4 should be disable.

this is what i have done
am tagging js,jq and hmtl maybe one could provide an assistance

html

```
          <input type="hidden" name="ttype[<?php echo $ix ?>]" value="<?php echo 
          $rowx['testtype']; ?>"/>
                                         
                                         
         <td colspan="0">  Result <br> 
        <div>
          <select name="negpos[<?php echo $ix ?>]"     style='width:50px'>
          <option selected value=''> Select One </option>
          <option value='Pos'> Positive</option>
          <option value='Neg'> Negative</option>
          <option  value='N/P'> Not Provided</option>
          </select>
          <span id="sresultInfo">
          </span>
          </div>
          </td> 

        
                                     
          <td><input type="text"   name="WBC[<?php echo $ix ?>]"size ="3" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="HGB[<?php echo $ix ?>]"size ="3" /></td>
           <td> <input type="text" name="RBC[<?php echo $ix ?>]" size ="3" value=""/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Lymph[<?php echo $ix ?>]"size ="3"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="MCV[<?php echo $ix ?>]" size ="3"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Gran[<?php echo $ix ?>]" size ="3"/></td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="MCH[<?php echo $ix ?>]" size ="3"/> </td>
```

js

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
     
    
         var ttyp =   document.getElementById("ttype").value  ;
 
            if (ttyp = "MPP" ){
 
          document.getElementById('WBC').disabled = true;
          document.getElementById('HBG').disabled = true;
          document.getElementById('RBC').disabled = true;

         } else {

          document.getElementById('WBC').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('HGB').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('RBC').disabled = false;

         }
     
       });
```

Comment: your inputs don't have ID attribute, but have NAME, and your javascript trying to search by ID. this code is not working totally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to this. The disabletext represents the text to match to disable and disablefieldids is the list of comma seperated value which contain id of the field to disable.

```js
 $('input').on('change', function() {
                var conditions = $(this).data();
                var inputValue = $(this).val();

                if(inputValue == conditions.disabletext) {
                    conditions.disablefieldids.split(",").map(function(id) {
                        $('#'+id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    })
                }else {
                    conditions.disablefieldids.split(",").map(function(id) {
                        $('#'+id).removeAttr('disabled');
                    })
                }
                  
                  
            })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-disabletext="test" data-disablefieldids="HGB,RBC"  name="WBC"size ="3" />
            </td>
           <td><input type="text" id="HGB" name="HGB"size ="3" /></td>
           <td> <input type="text" id="RBC" name="RBC" size ="3" value=""/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Lymph" name="Lymph"size ="3"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="MCV" name="MCV" size ="3"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Gran" name="Gran" size ="3"/></td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="MCH" name="MCH" size ="3"/> </td>
          </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing disable text and fields to input attributes I would like create one general object so it will give us more usability,

```
const InputCondition = [
            {"disabletext":"Test","disablefieldids":["HGB","RBC"]},
            {"disabletext":"ABC","disablefieldids":["MCV","MCV"]}
           ];
```

**here is the on keyup initialization (change as per your need)**

```
 $('#ttype').keyup(function () {
    func_makeInputdisable($(this).val());
});


// you can call this onload // pass the text value in param.


     function func_makeInputdisable(lookingForText) {

    let matches = InputCondition.find(x => 
   x.disabletext.toLowerCase() == lookingForText.trim().toLowerCase());
    if (typeof (matches) != 'undefined') {
        matches = matches.disablefieldids;
        //Remove all the disable inputs if in need
        $('.AllInputClass').removeAttr('disabled');

        if (matches.length > 0) {
            $.each(matches, (index, inputID) => {
                let $ele = $(`#${inputID}`);

                if (typeof ($ele) != 'undefined')
                    $ele.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            });
        }
    }
    else {
        $('.AllInputClass').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

// To enable textbox just add the same class on each input and use like,
**$('.AllInputClass').removeAttr('disabled');** placed in comment above function with class name "AllInputClass"

Comment: thanks its helpful but it remain disabled even after adding else $ele.attr('disabled', 'false'); to your code.  one other thing can this work  on page load?

Comment: I have updated the answer and use func_makeInputdisable in
 $(document).read(() => {

});

Comment: thanks but what i want is  <input type="text"   value ="ABC" name="WBC"size ="3" /> on load or refresh then disable text and not on change function

Comment: If I'm not wrong you want to disable input type on page refresh right.?
answer : $(document).load(() => { 
 $('#text').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

Comment: basically that what i want but how to use it on the code shared

Comment: as per your load func, try this $(document).ready(function(){
         var ttyptxt =   document.getElementById("ttype").value; 
          func_makeInputdisable(ttyptxt );     
            //unceomment the "$('.AllInputClass').removeAttr('disabled');" from func_makeInputdisable function and add calss "AllInputClass" to each input and there you go.
       });

Comment: thanks alot @Kd the solution is working but the problem is that its an array, so if i have three lines 1. ttype = "ABC" and it disables wbc,rbc,mcv, 2 ttype="test" > nothing is happening

Comment: I couldn't image your case so, would you please set code snippet to codepen and share a link and we will try to give you a prefect solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239973/discussion-between-phillip-chirazo-and-kd-nimavat).

Comment: https://codepen.io/ChirazoP/pen/JjrKMbg i have just indicated the array the values in the array will be populated in the table

Comment: https://codepen.io/kdnimavat/pen/MWEeGVZ
Here the full code you can access and test it.

Comment: i have added a picture on my question just to illustrate what is happening you can note that line 2 -4 nothing is happening

Comment: did you have a look at the picture above ?

Comment: I have, given code is same just change it as you need, in the picture we can see that same input id for each row. so just add one two line of code and make it work. I could do but try to debugged code in console and you will have idea what to do next.

Comment: i have tried numerous ways but am unable to find a solution